# What is a CGVector?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, vector-graphics

After searching the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html), I still cannot find a reasonable explanation for what a `CGVector` is. The only times it is mentioned in the documentation is when it shows what its `typedef` is.

```
struct CGVector {
   CGFloat dx;
   CGFloat dy;
};
typedef struct CGVector CGVector;
```

From basic geometry I know that `dx` means delta x, or change in x. The same goes for `dy`. With this knowledge, what is a `CGVector` (or just  any kind of vector) from a programming standpoint? If it helps, I am trying to understand a vector in the context of SpriteKit's `SKPhysicsBody` and velocity.

Comment: A CGVector corresponds to the familiar definition of a vector in mathematics.  Vectors are magnitudes of distance and direction.  What better way to show it for 2-dimensional planes like screens than a struct with change in x and change in y?

Comment: But we also have `CGSize`. There seems to be little difference between the two

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned, dx and dy represent change in x and change in y, respectively. That makes it a good candidate to represent the velocity of an object in two dimensions.